# Nginx automated /tmp cleanup?

Tags: nginx

I've installed Nginx on my vps

i found this message inside Nginx Admin

```
To automated /tmp cleanup add bellow cron 
0 */1 * * * /usr/sbin/tmpwatch -am 1 /tmp/nginx_client
via crontab -e command
```

where i should execute this line ?

```
 0 */1 * * * /usr/sbin/tmpwatch -am 1 /tmp/nginx_client
```

my vps centos 5 32 cpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the console of your VPS and do the following:

```
 $ crontab -e
```

Then, in the cron file (which schedules jobs using the `* * * * *` syntax that you can read more about [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)) enter that line:

```
0 */1 * * * /usr/sbin/tmpwatch -am 1 /tmp/nginx_client
```

This will execute the command `tmpwatch` every hour, on the hour.

`tmpwatch` will remove all files with a modified file time greater than 1 hour in the `/tmp/nginx_client` directory.

Comment: you mean execute this lines on ssh root ?

Answer (score 0):

another way...

```
0 * * * * find /tmp/nginx_client/ -type f -mtime +8 -delete > /dev/null 2>&1
```