# Is there a better way of cleaning old session files in Magento than using tmpwatch?

Tags: linux, magento, session

I have a Magento instance that stores sessions outside the database, using session files.

It is an inherited project running on a Debian Linux server, and it seems that there is nothing implemented to maintain and clean the drive (more even, to prevent the exhaustion of inodes due to and ever-growing amount of session files).

I'm rather new to Magento, but though I've looked for something, I didn't find an specific solution to do this for Magento.

So I'm thinking about using [tmpwatch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tmpwatch) to do this. For those who haven't used tmpwatch, it lets you delete all files in a folder that have not been modified in a given amount of time. Example:

`# tmpwatch 30d /path/to/folder/`

will remove all files that weren't modified in the last 30 days in `/path/to/folder/`. You don't need to use root, you just need to have permissions to purge the old files.

My question is, Am I missing something that fits better to resolve this issue in Magento? Just deleting files that have not been modified in the last 2-3 months seems a bit... rough.

When looking for tmpwatch on SO you may find [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484788/nginx-automated-tmp-cleanup/21484894#21484894), but when narrowed to tmpwatch and Magento, nothing pops up. That's why I think maybe I'm missing something important.

Thanks :)

Comment: PHP is supposed to do this, see among other answers, particularly the Sonassi answer here => http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41/how-should-i-handle-session-files-that-become-too-numerous